# Transit Timing Variation data for binaries

Tags: data-analysis, binary-star

Where can I find transit timing variation data (TTV) for binaries, please? Is there any database? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say binaries, I assume your excluding exoplanet systems right? Because there is quite a bit of data on those with respect to TTVs

Comment: Yes, I am excluding exoplanet systems.